# Parsing char to vector<float> for hog.setSVMdetector(vector<float>)

Tags: android, c++, opencv

I have a problem for parsing float from char in JNI-Android Application.This is my sample data :

```
0.00618567 0.00224441 0.002006603 0.001813437 0.003761207 -0.001850192 -0.001011893 -0.00342476 0.003790586 0.002385935 0.002647488 0.004411637 0.005938921 0.00698391 0.004522655 0.001524881 -0.002673242 -0.0002569943 -0.002495839 0.00230171 0.000844161 0.006387557 0.008135659 0.005583601 0.002238941 -0.001932641 -0.003518643 -0.0006784072 0.001636732 0.001213515 0.0021472 0.004911256 0.003613603 0.001362842 -0.0002172031 -0.002115535 -0.0002000824 0.001085831 0.003149634 0.003899722 0.004865647 0.002436467 0.0001896242 -0.001678405 -0.001909177 -0.002954236 0.001802054 0.003751467 0.004150682 0.005844797 0.002612064 0.003680898 -0.0005450704 -0.002621638 -0.002253087 0.0005009398 0.004602027 0.003445318 0.00632045 0.002706638 -0.001308871 -0.002082631 -0.001821213 -0.0005696003 0.002069579 0.006264412 0.004593662 0.005836432 0.0009420562 -0.003753015 -0.004050847 -0.001744672 -0.002664186 0.00101941 0.004568859 0.003175343 0.005315124
```

And this is a type of data `vector<float>` for `hog.setSVMdetector(const vector<float>& detector)`:

```
0.05359386f, -0.14721455f, -0.05532170f, 0.05077307f, 0.11547081f, -0.04268804f, 0.04635834f, -0.05468199f, 0.08232084f, 0.10424068f, -0.02294518f, 0.01108519f, 0.01378693f, 0.11193510f, 0.01268418f, 0.08528346f, -0.06309239f, 0.13054633f, 0.08100729f, -0.05209739f, -0.04315529f, 0.09341384f, 0.11035026f, -0.07596218f
```

this is my sample code `.cpp` in JNI :

```
extern "C"
jboolean
Java_com_example_franksyesipangkar_tourguide_CameraPreview_ImageProcessing
(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jint width, jint height, jbyteArray NV21FrameData, jintArray outPixels, jbyteArray b)

{

LOGD("JNIEnv");

    //convert jbyteArray to char
    jbyte *cmd = env->GetByteArrayElements(b, 0);
    LOGD("JNIEnvFeature");

    //char * feature = (char *)cmd;

    char feature[90600];
    memset(feature,0, sizeof(feature));
    memcpy(feature, cmd, strlen((char*)cmd));
```

In this code, a data in char feature which I want to parsing it to data like a type of data `hog.setSVMdetector(const vector<float>& detector)`.So, do you have an idea ?

Comment: So you need a way to take the numbers in the "feature" string, and push them into a std::vector<float>?

Comment: Allright @AdiLevin..Not only push them, but make data like `vector<float>` which a data have **,** before space..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can help you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <strstream>
#include <string>


std::vector<float> parse_delimeted_list_of_numbers(char* line, char delimeter)
{
    std::vector<float> vector_of_numbers;
    std::istrstream input_stream(line);
    std::string text;
    float number;
    while (std::getline(input_stream, text, delimeter)) {
        sscanf_s(text.c_str(), "%f", &number, text.size());
        vector_of_numbers.push_back(number);
    }
    return vector_of_numbers;
}

// A program to test that the above function works well
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
//  auto vector_of_numbers = parse_delimeted_list_of_numbers("234.0, 345, 465, 46456.0",',');
    auto vector_of_numbers = parse_delimeted_list_of_numbers("234.0 34 465 46456.0", ' ');
    for (auto number : vector_of_numbers)
        std::cout << number << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What for `int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){ }` ? @adi-levin

Comment: The _tmail part is just a test program to test that the function works. You don't need it.

Comment: Oh @adi-levin..What is a function char delimeter ?

Comment: The function parse_delimeted_list_of_numbers takes as input two arguments: a sequence of numbers in text format (which I named "line"), and a single character that designates the character used as separator between two numbers, in this case it is the space character ' '.

Comment: Oh...alright @adi-levin, I just look at `auto vector_of_numbers = parse_delimeted_list_of_numbers("234.0 34 465 46456.0", ' ');` for use this function...

Comment: Yes. vector_of_numbers is of type std::vector<float>. This is what you wanted, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100845/discussion-between-franksye-sipangkar-and-adi-levin).